# How to implement rocket engine in unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make rocket engine what would push Rigidbody. Working in Unity (2019 2of1 if needed).

I already tried using Constant force. It is not reacting on turns of a rocket (If it points upward, the rocket is moving upward, but theoretical, rocket must move backward).

I need engines to apply force in directions in that they are pointed. How to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

use Rigidbody.AddForce:
the transform must be the object that points in the direction where you want to push, so if you have a GameObject Rocket that your script is acting upon but not a component of, use Rocket.transform.forward.

```
rb.AddForce(transform.forward * thrust);
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html

if the rocket still flies in the wrong direction (backward instead of forward etc) use

```
rb.AddForce( - transform.forward * thrust);
```